# Python ValueError: too many values to unpack (For loop with nested variable)

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
col_cp1_tariff_time_weekday_1_hour = 0
col_cp1_tariff_time_weekday_2_hour = 7
col_cp1_tariff_time_weekday_3_hour = 9
col_cp1_tariff_time_weekday_4_hour = 19
col_cp1_tariff_time_weekday_5_hour = 21


weekday_cents_questions = [
    "What is the tariff from the weekday time %d:00? (in cents e.g 23.5)\n" % (col_cp1_tariff_time_weekday_1_hour),
    "What is the tariff from the weekday time %d:00? (in cents e.g 23.5)\n" % (col_cp1_tariff_time_weekday_2_hour),
    "What is the tariff from the weekday time %d:00? (in cents e.g 23.5)\n" % (col_cp1_tariff_time_weekday_3_hour),
    "What is the tariff from the weekday time %d:00? (in cents e.g 23.5)\n" % (col_cp1_tariff_time_weekday_4_hour),
    "What is the tariff from the weekday time %d:00? (in cents e.g 23.5)\n" % (col_cp1_tariff_time_weekday_5_hour)]


print("You will now be asked to enter the cost per kWh for the hourly times in a 24 hour clock.")

variable_bands = [0]

for question in weekday_cents_questions:
    try:
        q = question.format(variable_bands[-1])
        cents = int(input(q))
        variable_bands.append(cents)
    except (SyntaxError, ValueError):
        variable_bands.append(0)

[col_cp1_tariff_time_weekday_1_cents,
 col_cp1_tariff_time_weekday_2_cents,
 col_cp1_tariff_time_weekday_3_cents,
 col_cp1_tariff_time_weekday_4_cents,
 col_cp1_tariff_time_weekday_5_cents] = variable_bands

print(variable_bands)
```

When I execute, I receive the error:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 5)

Could you please show me how to fix. I am trying to assign the inputted integer into the variable_band variables.

Comment: `variable_bands` has 6 values and you're trying to assign these 6 values to 5 variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the line `variable_bands = [0]`, the size of this list is *already* 1. Then, your code appends five more elements to `variable_bands`, causing the size of this list to be 6, hence the `ValueError`.

Instead, change `variable_bands = [0]` to `variable_bands = []`.

*However*, after the change, you also have to watch that from `for question in weekday_cents_questions:` with all the try-except blocks, it will still not work because when the list is empty and you want to get the last list, it will still be an array index out of range traceback. Instead, you have to remove the `question.format()` part as it is not needed.

Your final code should be

```
variable_bands = []

for question in weekday_cents_questions:
    try:
        cents = int(input(question))
        variable_bands.append(cents)
    except (SyntaxError, ValueError):
        variable_bands.append(0)
```

**Here is a sample run of the modified program**

```
You will now be asked to enter the cost per kWh for the hourly times in a 24 hour clock.
What is the tariff from the weekday time 0:00? (in cents e.g 23.5)
1
What is the tariff from the weekday time 7:00? (in cents e.g 23.5)
2
What is the tariff from the weekday time 9:00? (in cents e.g 23.5)
3
What is the tariff from the weekday time 19:00? (in cents e.g 23.5)
omg
What is the tariff from the weekday time 21:00? (in cents e.g 23.5)
4
[1, 2, 3, 0, 4]
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should start your list `variable_bands` as and empty list, otherwise you'll have 6 elements instead of 5 in your list:

```
# Start an empty list
variable_bands = []

for question in weekday_cents_questions:
    try:
        # Check if it is empty, otherwise you'll get an IndexError
        if variable_bands == []:
            q = question.format(0)
        else:
            q = question.format(variable_bands[-1])
        cents = int(input(q))
        variable_bands.append(cents)
    except (SyntaxError, ValueError):
        variable_bands.append(0)
```

Comment: The `if variable_bands == []` part is not even necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Yes - I see the error now. Thanks for your help.